# Don't reposition Org Agenda buffer when starting TODO

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

When I change the state of a TODO item in Org-Agenda (i.e., by hitting `t`), it repositions the buffer so that that item is at the top of the screen.

I don't want it to do that — I'd rather just keep the buffer where it is (so I can see the entire day view, for example).

Is this configurable?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this behavior.  Can you give an example?

Comment: @SeanAllred Sure.  In `/tmp/x.org`, add a TODO scheduled for today.  Start `org-agenda` and add `/tmp/x.org` to `org-agenda-files` with `C-c [`.  Then refresh the agenda with `g` to see the TODO.  Change its state with `t` and you'll see the buffer reposition.  I did this with a minimal `.emacs.d/init.el` and still see the same behavior.

Comment: I do not see it :( https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17471132/tmp.mov

Comment: What's your org-version?

Comment: Wow @seanallred, you really don't.  Interesting.  Here's my version: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2si3x3zb5wq3qv/ScreenFlow.mov?dl=0.  Mine is Emacs.app on OS-X, Emacs 24.3, using the pre-installed version of org-mode (haven't been able to determine which version beyond that, yet).

Comment: Duh.  `org-version` returns 7.9.3f.  Ancient?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty old :)

Comment: I also recommend you consider updating to 24.4—there are a lot of new goodies :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed as of Org version [`8.2.6`](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tag/?id=release_8.2.6).

It was changed in this commit:

> [`6ba3b2 2014-03-18 19:54:02`](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=6ba3b2d03d277f6e8b67f9ca5ef6de19476bfc09)
>     org-agenda.el (org-agenda-todo): Restore the window correctly
>
> ```
> * org-agenda.el (org-agenda-todo): Always restore the window
> state after `org-agenda-change-all-lines' has been called.
>
> `org-agenda-change-all-lines' is narrowing to the line it needs to
> update.  In the narrowed state, `org-agenda-finalize' is called,
> which may lead to a change in the way the window is displayed.  We
> use `save-window-excursion' to ensure the window state is restored
> correctly.
>
> Thanks to Francesco Pizzolante for reporting this with a
> detailed recipe.
>
> diff --git a/lisp/org-agenda.el b/lisp/org-agenda.el
> index 54529d4..e20a55e 100644
> --- a/lisp/org-agenda.el
> +++ b/lisp/org-agenda.el
> @@ -8792,7 +8792,7 @@ the same tree node, and the headline of ...
>     (org-back-to-heading)
>     (move-marker org-last-heading-marker (point))))
>        (beginning-of-line 1)
> -      (save-excursion
> +      (save-window-excursion
>   (org-agenda-change-all-lines newhead hdmarker 'fixface just-one))
>        (when (org-bound-and-true-p org-clock-out-when-done)
>           (string-match (concat "^" (regexp-opt org-done-keywords-for-agenda))
> ```

If you don't want to update, simply apply the patch above.  It's only one line.

Comment: Thanks!  I suppose I could just live dangerously and try an update....

Comment: I, too, like to live dangerously.  Go for it—if you don't do anything exceptional with it, you likely won't notice a change.  (It now has a *fantastic* system for exporting, though.)

Comment: Took the plunge. So far so good.  I did hit the `org-with-silent-modifications` bug as described here[1], but it was quickly resolved.  [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291114/emacs-org-mode-how-to-automatically-process-to-pdf-on-save